# Subcategory Descriptions not always showing for every subcategory

Tags: magento-1.7, category, ce-1.7.0.2

I've got one of these situations which now is taking me already 2 days but I cannot get my head wrapped around it.
I just cannot find out why on two different subcategory pages, on one the description is shown, and on the other one, no matter what I do, it will not whow.

Here it works: https://www.persempretoys.nl/seo/kidkraft-poppenhuis all the way down on the page is the standard description for this category.
But here it doesn't: https://www.persempretoys.nl/seo/kidkraft-keuken
And these categories are built up in the exact same way.

So in the

```
app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/category/view.phtml
```

there is this section which invokes the description:

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
        <div class="category-description std">
            <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

It is a Magento 1.7.0.2 shop, but I cannot get this one solved quickly.
Any ideas from you ? Or anymore people who have encountered this ?

Edit: Background info added

Comment: Share Code that you are Using to fetch and some other info will also be useful

Comment: Hi Vishwas, it is all the default Magento 1.7.0.2 stuff, nothing special. But I will add it, no problem.

Comment: Did you tried flushing Cache ? checked the store view which you have entered short description  and trying view ?

Comment: Yes, flushed all caches and manually cleaned out the var/cache directory but that's not it. All the 'easy' things I have tried :)

Comment: Store View ? compilation ?

Comment: All perfectly fine Vishwas, this is exactly why I cannot figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

Admin - System - Index Management - Category Flat Data - Reindex data. That should do it.

Comment: Nope Vishwas, sorry but I tried all the apparent and easy things. Even manually cleaning the var/cache dir and deleting all sessions etc.